# Gradle custom provided scope include jars to war archive

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a problem with provided dependency scope. 
In my multiprojects with structure like below:

ROOT - ear

- ejb
- web

Web module depends on ejb.

This is my root build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

configurations {
provided
}

sourceSets {
main {
compileClasspath += configurations.provided
runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
test {
compileClasspath += configurations.provided
runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}
}

idea { module { scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided] } }

dependencies{
provided 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.1'
}
}
dependencies{
deploy project(path: ':web', configuration: 'archives')
deploy project(':ejb')
}

}
```

And in project ejb I defined provided dependencies:

```
dependencies{
    provided 'javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:3.2'
    provided 'javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2'
    provided 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
}
```

In web module:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies{
    providedCompile project(':ejb')
    providedCompile 'javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.2'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

}
```

> When using the Gradle war plugin you're enabled to declare
>   providedCompile dependencies to tell the compiler to include those
>   dependencies in the compile classpath, but to not make Gradle include
>   them in the packaged .war artifact.

But when my custom provided include this dependency to war archive:
'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.1'

How Can I resolve my problem?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by adding the following piece of code:

```
war {
    classpath = classpath - configurations.provided
}
```

Comment: Where did you add that?